# Web image gallery - what has been used creating it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have met an interesting image gallery transition surfing the web several times and now I'm interested in how such an elegant solution has been made.

Gallery can be found here: http://nullstuff.com/nullfolio/#/portfolio
The desired effect takes place when toggling between 'Everything' and 'Web Design'.

Could it be made purely with CSS?

Comment: You have a jquery plugin that have the effect that you want.

https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

Comment: To answer your question - yes, it could be made purely with CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the app.js source in the page, it's using the [jQuery Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To create such elegant gallery JQuery can be used.
You can find several JQuery galleries.

Look at this blog, I found http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all
It is not possible to add click events in css.

therefore it is javascript
This is known as an image carousel.

I made my own in jquery.

I can give you the source if you want.

Click on the image to see effect and see the url change and press back button.

You will find the previous page loaded with the effect.Moreover the scrollbar(horizontal) hides after poping which i think is made overflow-x:hidden in css.